# Spring mulitple rows with hibernate bean

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

We are migrating to spring & hibernate from struts1.x and JDBC.

Facing issue while adding multiple rows in jsp (like mapped properties in struts1.x) based on user preferences (Ex: Adding/deleting employees to Manager) in spring.

In service layer, getting Manager Object (as persistent object returned by hibernate )then displaying manager object in JSP. Employee row will be deleted by using java script/jquery from html form by user delete action, upon form submission spring does not delete in the respective employee from the list of employees of Manager object (model attribute). I have worked on some examples without hibernate where the object is being deleted from the list and works well but not in the hibernate prepared object.

ex: lets say Manager object have 3 employees as List when displaying on screen, when user will delete one employee row and submitted then spring needs to populate the Manager object with two employee objects as list since one employee is deleted by user in UI.

I suspect that, this behavior with PersistentBag implementation of Hibernate?

Anybody experienced this problem earlier? Any ideas would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

It might depends on how the pojo is declared..
Sure you are deleting a manager, but how is the manager connected to the employee?
If on the manager you have a Employee Object, you should have

```
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;
```

This way, if you delete the manager object, it will cascade delete the Employee object... 
Either your "cascade" is enforced via db, or it must be enforced via annotation.. if you're not doing either, of course nothing will happen...

Comment: thanks reply, issue is with spring mvc form population, my expectation is when employee (row on screen )object is deleted from html form then upon submit spring does not remove the respective employee object from the List of employees of Manager object. ex: lets say Manager object have 3 employees as List, when displaying on screen, manager will have 3 employees now user will delete one employee row and submitted then spring needs to populate the Manager object with two employee objects as list since one employee is deleted.